# Issue with pushing view from AppDelegate

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller, storyboard, uitabbarcontroller

My app consist of a UITabbarController as the root view controller. The view at index 0 is also embedded inside a UINavigatiionController but I'm having issues pushing my detail view controller onto view from the AppDelegate. I'm using URL schemes throughout my app to allow users to share their post on Facebook or Twitter. Below you will see my code for when the app receives the URL Scheme notification:

```
if ([[url scheme] isEqualToString:@"app"]) {

    if ([[url host] isEqualToString:@"post"]) {

        NSString *objectId = [[url path] stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"/" withString:@""];

        PFQuery *queryForObject = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"Post"];
        [queryForObject setCachePolicy:kPFCachePolicyCacheThenNetwork];
        [queryForObject getObjectInBackgroundWithId:objectId block:^(PFObject *post, NSError *error) {

            if (!error) {

                NSLog(@"Found object with ID, %@", post);

                UITabBarController *tabBarController = (UITabBarController *)self.window.rootViewController;
                [tabBarController setSelectedIndex:0];

                UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];

                self.navController = (UINavigationController *)[storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"mainNavy"];

                ECDDetailNewViewController *detailViewController = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"ShowDetailViewController"];
                [detailViewController setDetailItem:post];

                [self.navController pushViewController:detailViewController animated:YES];

            }
        }];

    }
```

Everything works up to tabbarController setSelected, but the view is never pushed.

What's the best way to push a view from AppDelegate? I'm using StoryBoards in my app.

Comment: Check `self.navController` is nil or not

Comment: I don't see anything that makes `self.navController` part of the controller hierarchy.  If the first tab already has a navigation controller, shouldn't you be using it instead of loading a new one?